# emberjs mixin vs extend

Tags: ember.js, ember-validations

I am thinking of using dockyard validations in my project

I have options as to how to use the Validations-Mixin from dockyard

- **Approach 1**  to have a BaseController which will mixin this Validations-Mixin and get the functionality in all controllers
- **Approach 2** use the Mixin directly.

Pros of 1
no need to import ember-validations in every file and mixin manually , and I get the functionality of validations in all the controllers.

Cons of 1 
Validations might not be required in all the controllers , may be it's required only in 50% of the cases, also might reorder the way existing controllers add the mixins.

Pros of 2
Simple, only who need the functionality will import and use it.

Cons of 2 
importing in each file where required and adding the mixin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use that mixin directly. Why?

Because there is no need to extend it in every controller in your app. Extending mixins is a way to obtain shared functionality between controllers that **share** that functionality. I am pretty sure that not *every* controller in your app needs validation.

From my experience I can say that only some percent of controllers use validations (it depends on the app, but it's just a rough mean value). Import the mixin where it's needed.

Comment: agree: always prefer composition over inheritance IMO